# Syntax to take user input from SQL and insert those values into a table in MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql

*So, I'm not sure how to go about this. I've installed and imported MySQL Connector.*

```
fit=sql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='xez23%',database='fitnesscentre')

                uID= int(input('Enter user ID: '))
                pwd= input('Enter password: ')
                wgt1=int(input('Enter your weight: '))
                bmi= float(input('Enter BMI: '))
                actlevel= int(input('Enter activity level in minutes: '))
                upd= input('Update? Y/N')
                if upd=='Y':
                    d=fit.cursor()
                    rec1='UPDATE userstats SET weight=%s, BMI=%s, activitylevel=%s WHERE ID=%d; '
```

**What do I do next?
This is the table userstats:
[userstats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdDF6.jpg)**

Answer (score 1):

i use this to input:

```
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
   user='root', password='*******', host='127.0.0.1', database='data')

cursor = conn.cursor()


insert_stmt = (
   "insert into datauser(nama_depan,nama_belakang,email,iat,at_hash)"
   "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
)
data = ('value', 'value', 'value', value, 'value')

try:
  
   cursor.execute(insert_stmt, data)
   
  
   conn.commit()

except:
  
   conn.rollback()

print("Data inserted")


conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

What to do next is call `execute()` on the cursor. The first argument is the SQL string with parameter placeholders. The next argument is a tuple containing the values you want to use for those placeholders, in the same order as the placeholders in the SQL string.

```
d.exec(rec1, (wgt1, bmi, actlevel, uID,))
```